# Autonumber in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How do I auto number when moving to next list item?

It seems that I can't trigger it.

Comment: This question was originally about how to get fixed numbering and answered here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/39461/in-org-mode-how-to-disable-auto-numbering-of-numbered-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that org mode is enabled (either by opening a filename ending in `.org`, or by manually triggering it with org-mode), you can auto-increment a numbered list by hitting `M-<RET>` (usually <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>enter</kbd>) after a list item, for example:

```
1. First entry (M-<RET>)
2.
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it just <RET>? Without the M?